# Use Chart.js & jQuery in Ionic Framework

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

We want to include Chart.js & jQuery in our Ionic/Angular project.

After installing through npm, we try to reference the files below like usual business:

```
<script src="../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

What are we doing wrong? We have also included a reference for just some reason in packages.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "chart": "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js"
```

If we use the CDN, it works... But why would I even use the npm to install things then? I don't get it...

- "@ionic-native/core": "~4.12.0"
- Ionic CLI version 6.4.1
- "ionic-angular": "3.9.2"
  We recieve the faulty message as seen below:

> Refused to execute script from
>   'http://localhost:8100/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js' because its
>   MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type
>   checking is enabled.

Complete error output:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: Chart is not defined
>   ReferenceError: Chart is not defined
>       at UIChart.webpackJsonp.500.UIChart.initChart (http://localhost:8100/build/0.js:173:26)
>       at UIChart.webpackJsonp.500.UIChart.ngAfterViewInit (http://localhost:8100/build/0.js:154:14)
>       at callProviderLifecycles (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:13123:18)
>       at callElementProvidersLifecycles (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:13090:13)
>       at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:13073:29)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14228:5)
>       at callViewAction (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14570:21)
>       at execComponentViewsAction (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14502:13)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14225:5)
>       at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:15473:42)
>       at c (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19752)
>       at c (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19461)
>       at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:20233
>       at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15660)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:5126:33)
>       at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15581)
>       at r.runTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10834)
>       at o (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7894)

A friend suggested we maybe need to install Browserify or Webpack. Gonna try that...

Answer (score 0):

If you use chart js through node_modules you don't need to include through `<script src="">`

When you execute `ionic serve` you load the node_modules and execute them.

Also you try to use `npm start` instead of `ionic serve` to check if can fix your problem.
Let me know how it is going.

Comment: Hey man! Tried removing the <script> tag interely and using npm start instead. But we just got referenceerror. When we used the CDN, it worked again. I don't get it :/

Comment: It is weird that doesn´t work with npm start. I am glad that now is working. If you want, you can try to npm uninstall chart. Then npm install. Then try npm start without the CDN  and see if it is working.

Comment: So weird, tried that too now. Didn't help either. Do you want me to put in the whole error output?

Comment: Yes please, put the error output. Meanwhile, you can do it with the CDN for the moment.

Comment: Added complete error output above. Also I'm going to try installing Browserify and later Webpack if the first won't help. It is extra weird that I now know how to input my own JavaScript files. But it won't link to the Chart.js or jQuery in node_modules...